# How to use NpgSql to insert an array of Strings into a Postgresql column

Tags: .net, arrays, string, postgresql-9.3, npgsql

I am trying to insert an array of strings into a column using .NET.  It is a legacy app in VB.NET but I can convert from C# easily.  Here is what I tried:

```
        p = New NpgsqlParameter("company_address", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array + NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
        p.Value = data.company_address     ' <--- array of strings
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
```

I either get an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'" with the above, or I tried using this format for the value:  '{"string1","string2","string3"}'
but then I get an error "Input string was not in the proper format". I got that same error when I also tried:  ARRAY['string1','string2','string3']

So do arrays always have to be converted to a string of some sort of format or can NpgSqlParameter somehow be used to accept a string array?

The field company_address is defined as String()  The Npgsql version is 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text` (bitwise or), not `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array + NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text`.

Another option is to omit NpgsqlDbType entirely and let Npgsql infer - when it sees array of strings it will automatically send the right type.

Comment: I did not see the prototype that allows for inferrance - worked like a charm - thanks!

Comment: @shay-rojansky  Is inference recommended? It doesn't seem that this enum is marked as flag-based, so I get this warning that seems like a good one to not ignore:

`Remove this bitwise operation; the enum 'NpgsqlDbType' is not marked with 'Flags' attribute.`

Comment: There's no particular reason to avoid inference; explicitly specifying NpgsqlDbType is typically only needed when there are multiple PG types that correspond to a given .NET type, and you need to select the non-default mapping (e.g. you want to send a `timestamp without time zone` parameter but DateTime maps to `timestamp with time zone` by default).

Comment: As for NpgsqlDbType not having [Flags], you're right - this is because this enum is a hybrid, with some values functioning as regular enum values (int, string) and other being combinable with flags (array, range). It may not be the best design, but it is what it is...